# CameraX PreviewView show all but record only an area

Tags: android, video, camera, android-camerax

What I want to do is show a rectangle over my `PreviewView` and only record the area inside of that rectangle even if PreviewView shows the whole camera.

I just want to save to a file what's inside the white rectangle, but I want the preview to show everything:
[image]

activity.xml:

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/textureView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/crop"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/background_drawable"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity.kt

```
  private fun startCamera() {
    val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)
    cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
        cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

        // The display information
        val metrics = DisplayMetrics().also { textureView.display.getRealMetrics(it) }
        // The ratio for the output image and preview
        val aspectRatio = aspectRatio(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels)
        // The display rotation
        val rotation = textureView.display.rotation

        val localCameraProvider = cameraProvider
            ?: throw IllegalStateException("Camera initialization failed.")

        // The Configuration of camera preview
        preview = Preview.Builder()
            .setTargetAspectRatio(aspectRatio) // set the camera aspect ratio
            .setTargetRotation(rotation) // set the camera rotation
            .build()

        // The Configuration of video capture
        videoCapture = VideoCapture.Builder().build()

        localCameraProvider.unbindAll() // unbind the use-cases before rebinding them

        try {
            // Bind all use cases to the camera with lifecycle
            camera = localCameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                this, // current lifecycle owner
                lensFacing, // either front or back facing
                preview, // camera preview use case
                videoCapture, // video capture use case
            )

            // Attach the viewfinder's surface provider to preview use case
            preview?.setSurfaceProvider(textureView.surfaceProvider)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(tag, "Failed to bind use cases", e)
        }
    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
}
```

I have tried ViewPort but that changes the preview too and that's not my end goal here and I want to record that exact X,Y where the white rectangle is and it seems like I can't specify that on the viewport?

```
 val viewPort =  ViewPort.Builder(Rational(width, height), rotation).build()
        val useCaseGroup = UseCaseGroup.Builder()
            .addUseCase(preview!!) //your preview
            .addUseCase(videoCapture!!)
            .setViewPort(viewPort)
            .build()
```

Documentation around CameraX is too messy with a lot of breaking changes from 1.0.0 to 1.1.0 I'm really struggling to find what I'm looking for here.

It works fine to record the whole camera if I don't set ViewPort, is just recording that area only that I'm struggling with.

Thanks.